# Total reflection in a solar collector?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

So, I was wondering how radiation is kept inside a solar thermal collector?
The sun light (or its photons) penetrates through the glass and is then absorbed by the absorber layer. In turn, the absorber layer radiates in the infrared. The glass layer is almost opaque for this wavelength and thus the thermal radiation is kept inside. That is kind of "semi-classical" picture.

My question is, can this process be also understood in terms of the classical concept of total reflection?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your first paragraph described the situation pretty well, but your second paragraph (and the question) doesn't stand on its own. If you'd like a quality answer, I suggest you enhanced that second paragraph (e.g. where did you think "total reflection" is needed to explain this?).

Comment: If you look up the reflectivity of glass in the NIR, that may help clarify the situation.  Further, in a purely heat-absorbing setup likethis (as opposed to photovoltaic), there's usually a heat sink on the other side to reduce the radiation loss from the absorber layer.

Answer (score 1):

No it is separate issue to total internal reflection.

The important thing here is frequency dependent emissivity of the materials. Very simply speaking, the absorber needs to have high emissivity in the optical and NIR region (so it strongly absorbs sunlight) and low emissivity in IR, so that the thermal energy is not radiated away. It is like a green house.

You can concentrated light using total internal reflection, read about luminescent solar concentrators.

I will update this answer with some diagrams from my lecture notes when I get back to my laptop.